# How do I add a class to an element's parent using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a music page set up and when the play button is clicked for a song, the class changes from `buttons_mp3j` to `buttons_mp3jpause`. When the class is `buttons_mp3jpause`, I want to target its parent `li.song` and add a class to it.

```
<li class="song">
    <div>
        <span>
            <span class="buttons_mp3jpause">
            </span>
        </span>
    </div>
</li>
```

I have tried the following code but it didn't work.

```
$(".buttons_mp3jpause").parents("li.song").addClass("playing");
```

Where did I go wrong?

Edit

```
$('.haiku-play').bind('click', function() {
    $('.haiku-player').jPlayer("pause");
})
```

Edit 2

```
<article>
    <ul>
        <li class="song">yadayada</li>
        <li class="song">yadayada</li>
        <li class="song">yadayada</li>
        <li class="song">yadayada</li>
    </ul>
</article>
<article>
    <ul>
        <li class="song">yadayada</li>
        <li class="song">yadayada</li>
        <li class="song">yadayada</li>
        <li class="song">yadayada</li>
    </ul>
</article>
<article>
    <ul>
        <li class="song">yadayada</li>
        <li class="song">yadayada</li>
        <li class="song">yadayada</li>
        <li class="song">yadayada</li>
    </ul>
</article>
```

Comment: Works perfectly for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Kh7K9/

Comment: Please post all your script, not only that line.

Comment: @billyonecan Ok, I added it to the original post.

Comment: The code you added seem to be ok too. Where are you changing the classes `buttons_mp3j` and `buttons_mp3jpause`?

Comment: @Desi @billyonecan was correct, you cannot use `bind()` that way on dynamic HTML.  Depending on your jQuery version, you will need to use `live()` or `on()` as a delegate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned in the question, you're assigning the class `buttons_mp3jpause` dynamically, so you need to attach a handler to an element which exists in the DOM on page load, and delegate it to the dynamic class, using jQuery's [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events):

```
$('.song').on('click', '.buttons_mp3jpause', function() {
    $(this).closest('li.song').addClass('playing');
});
```

#### In response to first comment:

Simply remove the `playing` class from all other `song` elements (the below presumes that all of your `song` elements are `siblings`!):

`.addClass('playing').siblings('li.song').removeClass('playing');`

#### In response to your last comment:

The easiest thing in this situation would be to simply remove the `playing` class from all `song` elements, and then just add it to the relevant one:

```
$('li.song').removeClass('playing');
$(this).closest('li.song').addClass('playing');
```

#### Complete example:

```
$('.song').on('click', '.buttons_mp3jpause', function() {
    $('li.song').removeClass('playing');
    $(this).closest('li.song').addClass('playing');
});
```

Comment: Ok, this works. The only problem is that when I click on another play button, the previous `playing` class on the last play button remains. I want the class `playing` to only show up on the song currently playing. How can I do this? And thank you!

Comment: So basically when the class is `buttons_mp3j`, the class should be removed.

Comment: Is there a solution for when the `song` elements are not siblings? I have three tabs and each tab contains a list of songs. I noticed that, with your solution, if I click on a song in one tab, and then navigate to another tab and click on a song in there, both songs now have the class `playing`. How can I make sure that only one song has the class `playing` at any given time?

Comment: There's definitely a solution. It all depends on the structure of your markup though. Without seeing it I wouldn't be able to give you an answer

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused. Do I keep the previous block of code and add this to it?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".buttons_mp3jpause").parent().parent().parent().addClass("playing");
```

If you want to target the parent.

```
$(".buttons_mp3jpause").closest("li.song").addClass("playing");
```

Or you can use closest to find the closest li with class song

Comment: Is the assumption that the `parents()` with a selector the problem?  It doesn't sound right to me.